# Can JPA persist data in JSON format?

Tags: json, jpa, serialization, jackson

We have some fairly large Java POJO's that we serialize and save to the database as LOB's just cuz its easier than having 100 different tables to handle our Strings, Integer, Collection fields.  These seems icky if we ever need to change the Java objects themselves.

Would saving them as serialized JSON be a better approach?  Is there a best practice for this?  I'm wondering whether JPA can just automatically serialize/deserialize using something like Jackson.

EDIT: Since people seem to be asking about this, here is the justification:

- This is a Java class used to save form field information.  There are 100 fields.
- 20 of the fields are Collections; therefore any queries on this data would require 20 different joins for each of the tables backing the collections
- 99% of these fields are empty because the fields are all optional; therefore 21 different mostly empty tables is wasteful
- There will NEVER be queries against these individual tables.  The data is always retrieve all at once.

So we do have some kind of reason for doing it this way.

Comment: What would be the use of JPA outside the relationnal world?

Comment: JPA is an API for persistence. Not defining HOW things are persisted.

Comment: We are using JPA for OR but, in this circumstance where we have a POJO of simple fields and collections it seemed easier to just serialize the whole thing and store it in one place.  Also, this object is constantly changing due to adding more and more fields.  Seemed much simpler than modifying the database every time.

Comment: If it helps, this Object holds search form field values for a web page for saved searching.   Just plain Strings and Collections of Strings.

Comment: So you are using a relational database in a completely non-relational way. Maybe an alternative persistence technologuy may be a better fit? See, for example MongoDb with http://mongojack.org/